# Why can a Swift constant be used as a loop index?

Tags: swift

I know this Swift code is valid:

```swift
let index = 0
for index in (1...9) {
    print(index)  // index changes value from 1 to 9
}
```

But then if you say 
`index += index`
you get the error

> "Cannot assign to value: 'index' is a 'let' constant"

So, if index is a constant why is it ok to use it in the loop where its value will change?

Comment: Your `let index` and `for index` refer to completely different variables called `index` [due to Scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). If you remove the `let index` your `for index` will still be valid. That `for index` is *redeclared* on each iteration of the loop. It doesn't *change* values.

Comment: I suggest you to check the difference between let and var in this post -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-and-let-in-javascript/

Comment: Great clarification, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> So, if index is a constant why is it ok to use it in the loop where its value will change?

You could think of `index` as being newly created and initialized each time through the loop, just as a variable declared inside the loop's body would be. It makes sense to use `let` here because normally you don't change the loop counter inside the loop.

**Update:** After the edit, the code makes more sense, and pkamb's comment really is more clear: the `index` that you declare with `let index = 0` is a different variable from the `index` used in the `for` loop.